# ASP.NET MVC: Accept JSON in Action as Anonymous Object

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, post

I am making a `POST` Ajax request to a controller action with JSON data like below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/AssembleProducts/UpdateProduct",
    data: JSON.stringify({ Product: Product }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

The action method looks like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateProduct(Product Product)
{

}
```

I can accept the JSON data as `Product` but I want to be able to accept it as Anonymous Object . So, that I do not need a `Type` in order to accept the data. I tried with `dynamic` and `object` keywords for parameter type instead of `Product` but still fare unsuccessful even in finding a relevant topic online.

Please suggest on this situation.

Comment: Why you want to accept `Anonymous object`? What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Murali I am trying to get the data sent from client. But some properties are just flags for server side conditionals so I do not need them in my model/type and making another whole set of DTOs for just few flag properties seems overkill to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

Client side:

```
data: { product: JSON.stringify(Product) }
```

Server side:

```
string productJson = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["product"];

Product p = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Product>(productJson);
```

Comment: I think the same thing is being done here what I said I can do already. There are certain properties being sent from the client that do not map to my Model type and I also do not want to create another model to get the value of the property. That is why I was thinking of anonymous object population.

Comment: @Md.lbrahim Then use `DeserializeObject` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserializeobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. `DeserializeObject` seems to be the one I was looking for. But I cannot get the whole JSON as string. Because I am getting no `Current` property on `HttpContext`. But I tried `HttpContext.Request.Form["product"]` and it returns null. Any suggestions?

Comment: Got it! I sent the whole JSON as string. Parsed the passed string with `var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(product);`. It returned an anonymous object with my data in it. FTR, `var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(product);` and `var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object>(product);` has the same result.Thanks for pointing me to the right direction @Johan

Answer (score 1):

Just so I'm clear: I am reading this as follows: you have a model Product:

```
class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

You want to post the product with addtional metadata:

```
var productJsonObject = {
    ProductId: 1,
    ProductName: 'widget',
    MetaField: 'xyz'
}
```

If this is the case, to get MetaField in your action, you can try querying the value provider directly:

```
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateProduct(Product Product)
{
    var metaField = ControllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("MetaField");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code will help in future. But there are hierarchies of flags in the JSON and I'd just like to parse the whole JSON as an `Object` or Anonymous type. That's it.